# Why would "a.getClass()" cause a Null Pointer Exception when "a" can be printed in the console?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

While I was testing the eclipse JDT package, this following code caused a Null Pointer Exception.

```
parse.findDeclaringNode(method.resolveMethodBinding()).getClass();
```

The strange thing is the following code,

```
System.out.println("Binding start: " + parse.findDeclaringNode(method.resolveMethodBinding()));
```

prints the following:

```
Binding start: public static int test(){
  return 1;
}
```

So clearly, what's returned from `parse.findDeclaringNode(method.resolveMethodBinding())` is not null.

However, despite printing something, adding toString() as below also gives a Null Pointer Exception, which suggests that the printing didn't even happen via "toString()":

```
parse.findDeclaringNode(method.resolveMethodBinding()).toString();
```

Before I explain what the code is expected to do, here is the console output of the exception from running `"parse.findDeclaringNode(method.resolveMethodBinding()).getClass();"` :

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2018-01-23 20:46:17.150
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(AbstractContributionItem.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.lambda$2(AbstractContributionItem.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4238)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3817)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.vogella.jdt.astsimple.handlers.SampleHandler.createAST(SampleHandler.java:89)
    at de.vogella.jdt.astsimple.handlers.SampleHandler.analyseMethods(SampleHandler.java:52)
    at de.vogella.jdt.astsimple.handlers.SampleHandler.execute(SampleHandler.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    ... 37 more
```

Let me explain what `parse.findDeclaringNode(method.resolveMethodBinding()))` is.

"parse" is a [CompilationUnit](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FCompilationUnit.html) and "method" is a [MethodInvocation](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FMethodInvocation.html). `parse.findDeclaringNode(method.resolveMethodBinding())` should return an [ASTNode](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FASTNode.html). Eclipse recognizes this and so if I type that line and add a period at the end, it suggests me methods of ASTNode.

Moreover, typing `System.out.println(parse.findDeclaringNode(method.resolveMethodBinding()) instanceof String);` makes Eclipse complain `Incompatible conditional operand types ASTNode and String`. Hence, even the imported package suggests that ASTNode should be returned.

However, `System.out.println(parse.findDeclaringNode(method.resolveMethodBinding()) instanceof ASTNode);` prints false.

I have no idea what `parse.findDeclaringNode(method.resolveMethodBinding())` is actually returning then.

===========UPDATE===============

Strange thing happened when I did `ASTNode test = parse.findDeclaringNode(method.resolveMethodBinding());`. The Eclipse debugger shows "test" to be null and even testing with `test == null` returns true.

So apparently `parse.findDeclaringNode(method.resolveMethodBinding())` returns something that can be printed but when assigned as an ASTNode object it becomes null.

Comment: So is that code line 89 in SampleHandler?

Comment: Just wondering, is following a copy-paste error or are you calling getClass()/toString() on something else?   **parse.findDeclaringNode(method.resolveMethodBinding())**).getClass();

Comment: Seems you are getting a method not a class.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes it's on that line

Comment: @Rahul  Yes it was just a typo on this post. The actual source code doesn't have that typo.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz  If I'm getting a method, why would there be something showing up when you print?

Comment: First, you should follow the guidelines to ask questions here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so the people trying to help you gets better chances on doing so :). A few doubts: what's parse object?, what are you trying to do? did you trying hooking a debugger to your code?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I feel like any more information will distract from the point: "How could there possibly be a Null Pointer Exception for x.getClass() when  x itself can be printed"

Comment: The object x can be printed but doesn't necessarily mean that getClass() is implemented or accessible. What you see in the print call is the result of the toString() implementation. That's why I suggested to use the debugger as it can give you detailed information on the object.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz But it's not the result of the "toString()" because as I mentioned, even explicitly calling "toString()" gives a Null Pointer Exception. Can you tell me what kind of information I can get via a debugger?

Comment: Well, a lot! you set a breakpoint and the IDE debugger will show all the variables present up to this point, it also allows to select code fragments and evaluate them on the fly just to name a few capabilities. What IDE are you using?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Sorry, let me rephrase that. Can you tell me what information I should try to look for with a debugger for my specific example? I am using Eclipse

Comment: The type of the object is the first one!. The debugger should allow you to drill down the attributes of the object. Just try it and you will be surprised. In fact, I'm surprised how you ended up with this low level question without knowing what a debugger can offer ;-) :-p

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I have updated the post with information I gathered while using the debugger. Could you please look and see what else I can gather from the debugger?

Comment: You only say that you have printed using `System.out.println(parse.findDeclaringNode(method.resolveMethodBinding()) instanceof ASTNode)` and get `false` - this is consistent with `findDeclaringNode` returning `null`. (`null` is not an instance of anything).

Comment: @greg-449 I mention in the beginning of the post that parse.findDeclaringNode(method.resolveMethodBinding()) prints something. (too long to copy in comment)

Comment: Easiest explanation would be: at the time when you call sysout you get a value, but later when you call .getClass() you have a null. Same method call doesn't guarantee same return value. To really prove you have the same value in both cases assign it to a local variable and work from there. BTW, recent versions of Eclipse even show the return value of a method right after you step out of it during debugging, so you should clearly see what values are involved.

Comment: It's not an easy case since the moment that debugger shows null. Try posting the question on JDT Eclipse forum.

Comment: I'd claim that "returns something that can be printed but when assigned as an ASTNode object it becomes null." is simply impossible. If you want more help, you should show us a coherent piece of code showing in a sequence of statements that the same thing is non-null first and triggers NPE later. So far, all we have is the report that a certain invocation *sometimes* answers null and *sometimes* something that can be printed. <shrug>